# How to debug the Sony imx415 camera connect with rk3588

Tags: arm, open-source, sony, android-hardware, sony-camera-api

I handle on an ArmSoM-W3 (RK3588) project,but tried couple times still unable to access the imx415 camera.In my limited experience with imx415 camera I have looked around and apparently I have got the solution here below.Wanted to know if it’s good practice to do that and what would be the best way to do that?

## 1、Environment

- [Mastering RK3588 from Beginner to Expert] Series Contents
- SoC: rk3588
- Sensor: imx415
- Board: ArmSoM-W3
- Linux: 5.10

## 2、Introduction：imx415

- Brand：SONY
- Sensor：IMX415
- Interface：MIPI CSI

## 3、Driver porting

Rockchip provides a camera_module_support_list for their solutions.

For this ArmSoM-W3 (RK3588) project, the IMX415 (sensor) was selected from Rockchip's support list.

### 3.1 Driver Source Files and Corresponding Scripts

There is no need to port the driver,because the default SDK from Rockchip has pre-integrated drivers for all supported camera models, compiled into the kernel.

Confirm the following information on the driver porting:

- Source Code

`3588_linux/3588_linux5.10_v1.0.5/kernel/drivers/media/i2c/imx415.c 3588_linux/3588_linux5.10_v1.0.5/kernel/drivers/media/i2c/Makefile 3588_linux/3588_linux5.10_v1.0.5/kernel/drivers/media/i2c/Kconfig 3588_linux/3588_linux5.10_v1.0.5/kernel/arch/arm64/configs/rockchip_linxu_defconfig`

- Makefile Script

`obj-$(CONFIG_VIDEO_IMX415)  += imx415.o`

- Kconfig Script

```
config VIDEO_IMX415
    tristate "Sony IMX415 sensor support"
    depends on I2C && VIDEO_V4L2 && VIDEO_V4L2_SUBDEV_API
    depends on MEDIA_CAMERA_SUPPORT
    help
      This is a Video4Linux2 sensor driver for the Sony
      IMX415 camera.

      To compile this driver as a module, choose M here: the
      module will be called imx415.
```

- Driver Macro Switch

`CONFIG_VIDEO_IMX415=y`

### 3.2 dts Device Tree

1）Camera Connection Diagram

The key pins connecting IMX415 to the SoC include: i2c, rst, pwdn, mclk, MIPI Clk, MIPI Data

2） Schematics

From the schematics, the key pin mappings are:

reset signal：gpio4 A0
power0 down signal：gpio1 B0
I2C channel：3
clock：CLK_MIPI_CAMARAOUT_M3

3）Device Tree Node

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: (GPL-2.0+ OR MIT)
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2022 Rockchip Electronics Co., Ltd.
 *
 */

/ {
    compatible = "radxa,rock-5b", "rockchip,rk3588";

    camera_pwdn_gpio: camera-pwdn-gpio {
        status = "okay";
        compatible = "regulator-fixed";
        regulator-name = "camera_pwdn_gpio";
        regulator-always-on;
        regulator-boot-on;
        enable-active-high;
        gpio = <&gpio1 RK_PB0 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&cam_pwdn_gpio>;
    };

    clk_cam_24m: external-camera-clock-24m {
        status = "okay";
        compatible = "fixed-clock";
        clock-frequency = <24000000>;
        clock-output-names = "clk_cam_24m";
        #clock-cells = <0>;
    };
};

&i2c3 {
    status = "okay";

    imx415: imx415@1a {
        status = "okay";
        compatible = "sony,imx415";
        reg = <0x1a>;
        clocks = <&cru CLK_MIPI_CAMARAOUT_M3>;
        clock-names = "xvclk";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&mipim0_camera3_clk>;
        power-domains = <&power RK3588_PD_VI>;
        pwdn-gpios = <&gpio1 RK_PB0 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        reset-gpios = <&gpio4 RK_PA0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        rockchip,camera-module-index = <0>;
        rockchip,camera-module-facing = "back";
        rockchip,camera-module-name = "CMK-OT2022-PX1";
        rockchip,camera-module-lens-name = "IR0147-50IRC-8M-F20";
        port {
            imx415_out0: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&mipidphy0_in_ucam0>;
                data-lanes = <1 2 3 4>;
            };
        };
    };

    camera_imx219: camera-imx219@10 {
        status = "disabled";
        compatible = "sony,imx219";
        reg = <0x10>;

        clocks = <&clk_cam_24m>;
        clock-names = "xvclk";

        rockchip,camera-module-index = <0>;
        rockchip,camera-module-facing = "back";
        rockchip,camera-module-name = "rpi-camera-v2";
        rockchip,camera-module-lens-name = "default";

        port {
            imx219_out0: endpoint {
                remote-endpoint = <&mipidphy0_in_ucam1>;
                data-lanes = <1 2>;
            };
        };
    };
};

&csi2_dphy0_hw {
    status = "okay";
};

&csi2_dphy0 {
    status = "okay";

    ports {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        port@0 {
            reg = <0>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            mipidphy0_in_ucam0: endpoint@1 {
                reg = <1>;
                remote-endpoint = <&imx415_out0>;
                data-lanes = <1 2 3 4>;
            };

            mipidphy0_in_ucam1: endpoint@2 {
                reg = <2>;
                remote-endpoint = <&imx219_out0>;
                data-lanes = <1 2>;
            };
        };

        port@1 {
            reg = <1>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            csidphy0_out: endpoint@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                remote-endpoint = <&mipi2_csi2_input>;
            };
        };
    };
};

&mipi2_csi2 {
    status = "okay";

    ports {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        port@0 {
            reg = <0>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            mipi2_csi2_input: endpoint@1 {
                reg = <1>;
                remote-endpoint = <&csidphy0_out>;
            };
        };

        port@1 {
            reg = <1>;
            #address-cells = <1>;
            #size-cells = <0>;

            mipi2_csi2_output: endpoint@0 {
                reg = <0>;
                remote-endpoint = <&cif_mipi2_in0>;
            };
        };
    };
};

&rkcif {
    status = "okay";
};

&rkcif_mipi_lvds2 {
    status = "okay";

    port {
        cif_mipi2_in0: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&mipi2_csi2_output>;
        };
    };
};

&rkcif_mipi_lvds2_sditf {
    status = "okay";

    port {
        mipi_lvds2_sditf: endpoint {
            remote-endpoint = <&isp0_vir0>;
        };
    };
};

&rkcif_mmu {
    status = "okay";
};

&rkisp0 {
    status = "okay";
};

&isp0_mmu {
    status = "okay";
};

&rkisp0_vir0 {
    status = "okay";

    port {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        isp0_vir0: endpoint@0 {
            reg = <0>;
            remote-endpoint = <&mipi_lvds2_sditf>;
        };
    };
};

&pinctrl {
    camera {
        cam_pwdn_gpio: cam-pwdn-gpio {
            rockchip,pins = <1 RK_PB0 RK_FUNC_GPIO &pcfg_pull_up>;
        };
    };
};
```

The device tree information is ultimately converted into an i2c_client, and passed to the IMX415 driver imx415_probe(){ compatible = "imx415"; needs to align with of_match_table in the driver for consistency.

```
rockchip,camera-module-index = <0>;
rockchip,camera-module-facing = "back";
rockchip,camera-module-name = "CMK-OT2022-PX1";
rockchip,camera-module-lens-name = "IR0147-50IRC-8M-F20";
```

The matching is for the iq files under external\camera_engine_rkaiq\iqfiles\isp3x.

## 4、Debugging Skills

### 4.1 Boot Log

```
root@linaro-alip:/# dmesg | grep imx415
[    2.547754] imx415 3-001a: driver version: 00.01.08
[    2.547767] imx415 3-001a:  Get hdr mode failed! no hdr default
[    2.547819] imx415 3-001a: Failed to get power-gpios
[    2.547826] imx415 3-001a: could not get default pinstate
[    2.547831] imx415 3-001a: could not get sleep pinstate
[    2.547850] imx415 3-001a: supply dvdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.547918] imx415 3-001a: supply dovdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.547945] imx415 3-001a: supply avdd not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.613843] imx415 3-001a: Detected imx415 id 0000e0
[    2.613890] rockchip-csi2-dphy csi2-dphy0: dphy0 matches m00_b_imx415 3-001a:bus type 5
[   18.386174] imx415 3-001a: set fmt: cur_mode: 3864x2192, hdr: 0
[   18.389067] imx415 3-001a: set exposure(shr0) 2047 = cur_vts(2250) - val(203)
```

### 4.2 Inspect IMX415 Device

After successful driver loading:

- View camera device nodes:

```
root@linaro-alip:/rockchip-test# ls /dev/video* -l
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  0  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  1  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 10  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video10
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 11  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video11
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 12  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video12
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 13  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video13
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 14  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video14
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 15  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video15
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 16  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video16
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 17  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video17
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 18  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video18
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 19  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video19
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  2  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video2
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 20  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video20
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  3  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video3
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  4  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video4
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  5  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video5
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  6  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video6
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  7  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video7
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  8  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video8
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81,  9  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video9
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       7  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video-camera0 -> video11
-rw-rw----  1 root video      4  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video-dec0
-rw-rw----  1 root video      4  8月  7 15:26 /dev/video-enc0
```

### 4.3 **Inspect Device Information in sysfs**

The kernel allocates device information files for the camera under /sys/class/video4linux directory.

```
root@linaro-alip:grep imx415 /sys/class/video4linux/v*/name
root@linaro-alip:/rockchip-test# grep imx415 /sys/class/video4linux/v*/name
/sys/class/video4linux/v4l-subdev2/name:m00_b_imx415 3-001a
```

```
root@linaro-alip:/rockchip-test# grep "" /sys/class/video4linux/v*/name | grep mainpath
/sys/class/video4linux/video11/name:rkisp_mainpath
```

### 4.4 **Inspect Topology** media-ctl -d /dev/media0 -p

```
root@linaro-alip:/rockchip-test# media-ctl -d /dev/media0 -p
Media controller API version 5.10.110

Media device information
------------------------
driver          rkcif
model           rkcif-mipi-lvds2
serial
bus info
hw revision     0x0
driver version  5.10.110

Device topology
- entity 1: stream_cif_mipi_id0 (1 pad, 11 links)
            type Node subtype V4L flags 0
            device node name /dev/video0
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 5: stream_cif_mipi_id1 (1 pad, 11 links)
            type Node subtype V4L flags 0
            device node name /dev/video1
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 9: stream_cif_mipi_id2 (1 pad, 11 links)
            type Node subtype V4L flags 0
            device node name /dev/video2
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 13: stream_cif_mipi_id3 (1 pad, 11 links)
             type Node subtype V4L flags 0
             device node name /dev/video3
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 17: rkcif_scale_ch0 (1 pad, 11 links)
             type Node subtype V4L flags 0
             device node name /dev/video4
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 21: rkcif_scale_ch1 (1 pad, 11 links)
             type Node subtype V4L flags 0
             device node name /dev/video5
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 25: rkcif_scale_ch2 (1 pad, 11 links)
             type Node subtype V4L flags 0
             device node name /dev/video6
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 29: rkcif_scale_ch3 (1 pad, 11 links)
             type Node subtype V4L flags 0
             device node name /dev/video7
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 33: rkcif_tools_id0 (1 pad, 11 links)
             type Node subtype V4L flags 0
             device node name /dev/video8
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 37: rkcif_tools_id1 (1 pad, 11 links)
             type Node subtype V4L flags 0
             device node name /dev/video9
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 [ENABLED]
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 []

- entity 41: rkcif_tools_id2 (1 pad, 11 links)
             type Node subtype V4L flags 0
             device node name /dev/video10
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":1 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":2 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":3 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":4 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":5 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":6 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":7 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":8 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":9 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":10 []
                <- "rockchip-mipi-csi2":11 [ENABLED]

- entity 45: rockchip-mipi-csi2 (12 pads, 122 links)
             type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown flags 0
             device node name /dev/v4l-subdev0
        pad0: Sink
                [fmt:SGBRG10_1X10/3864x2192 field:none
                 crop.bounds:(12,16)/3840x2160
                 crop:(12,16)/3840x2160]
                <- "rockchip-csi2-dphy0":1 [ENABLED]
        pad1: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad2: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad3: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad4: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad5: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad6: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad7: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad8: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad9: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad10: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 [ENABLED]
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 []
        pad11: Source
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id0":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id1":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id2":0 []
                -> "stream_cif_mipi_id3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch2":0 []
                -> "rkcif_scale_ch3":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id0":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id1":0 []
                -> "rkcif_tools_id2":0 [ENABLED]

- entity 58: rockchip-csi2-dphy0 (2 pads, 2 links)
             type V4L2 subdev subtype Unknown flags 0
             device node name /dev/v4l-subdev1
        pad0: Sink
                [fmt:SGBRG10_1X10/3864x2192@10000/300000 field:none
                 crop.bounds:(12,16)/3840x2160]
                <- "m00_b_imx415 3-001a":0 [ENABLED]
        pad1: Source
                -> "rockchip-mipi-csi2":0 [ENABLED]

- entity 63: m00_b_imx415 3-001a (1 pad, 1 link)
             type V4L2 subdev subtype Sensor flags 0
             device node name /dev/v4l-subdev2
        pad0: Source
                [fmt:SGBRG10_1X10/3864x2192@10000/300000 field:none
                 crop.bounds:(12,16)/3840x2160]
                -> "rockchip-csi2-dphy0":0 [ENABLED]
```

From entity 63 information we can see:

The full entity name is: m00_b_imx415 3-001a

It is a V4L2 subdev (Sub-Device) Sensor
Its node is /dev/v4l-subdev2, applications (e.g. v4l2-ctl) can open it for configuration

It has only one output (Source) node, labeled pad0

Its output format is [fmt:SGBRG10_1X10/3864x2192@10000/300000 field:none

crop.bounds:(12,16)/3840x2160], where SBGGR10 is an mbus-code abbreviation

Its Source pad0 links to pad0 of "rockchip-csi2-dphy0", and current status is ENABLED.

media-ctl -d /dev/media1 -p

```
- entity 6: rkisp_mainpath (1 pad, 1 link)
            type Node subtype V4L flags 0
            device node name /dev/video11
        pad0: Sink
                <- "rkisp-isp-subdev":2 [ENABLED]
```

## 5、Testing

Once debugging  worked, running gst-launch-1.0 enables to view the input from the imx415 camera directly:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video11 ! video/x-raw,format=NV12,width=3840,height=2160, framerate=30/1 ! xvimagesink
```